# Why does Swing default 'Graphics' and not 'Graphics2D'?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, graphics2d

Why would they not default to `Graphics2D` if all of `Graphics` is also included in `Graphics2D`?
I seem to almost always cast / create a `Graphics2D` object in all my painting overrides.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics paramGraphics){
   super.paintComponent(paramGraphics);
   Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) paramGraphics.create();
   // RenderingHints etc.
 }
```

Comment: Not all Graphics is in fact guaranteed to be Graphics2D. Yes it is that way, I believe if you're drawing to the screen, but it may not be (I believe) always the case if you're printing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compatibility with AWT that only supported `Graphics`. Swing's components extend `java.awt.Component` that has a `getGraphics` method that returns only a `Graphics` object. At the time Swing was created (Java 1.1/1.2) Java didn't know covariance. An overriden method with a different (subclass of original) return type was not allowed even when the return type is not part of a method's signature. With today's language feature this is allowed and would probably be done differently, i.e. the return type would be changed to `Graphics2D`. At that time the only way would have been to either add a new method (like `getGraphics2D`) or completely break easy interoperatibility with AWT.

Comment: Even in 1.7 you can't have a contravariant parameter, which is where you perhaps most often see ye olde (1D?) `Graphics`. For a more specific return type, `create2D` and the like could have done the trick.